# is a set of equivalence classes in R x R countable?

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, real-numbers

An equivalence class in R x R is uncountable but is the set of equivalence classes in R x R countable?

Comment: What relation are you thinking of? Equivalence classes can be of any cardinality depending on the relation.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not well-defined, here's why.

Let $E$ be an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $E \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.
If you do not specify anything further about $E$, an equivalence class of $E$ could be finite, countably infinite or uncountable.
Also, there could be countably or uncountably many equivalence classes, depending on how one defines $E$.

Here are some examples.
You should check that they are indeed equivalence relations.

1. $xEy$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.
   Then there is exactly one equivalence class, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$, and it's uncountable.
2. $xEy$ if and only if there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x-y=n$. The equivalence classes are the sets $x + \mathbb{Z}$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, each class is countably infinite and there are uncountably many classes.
3. $xEy \iff \lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor y \rfloor$. Then the equivalence classes are the intervals $[n, n+1)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, each class is uncountable, and there are countably infinitely many equivalence classes.
4. $xEy \iff x = y$. Then the singletons $\{x\}$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ are the equivalence classes, and there are uncountably many of them.